# Trying to convert nasnet tensorflow model to caffemodel. cell_stem_1/1x1 output is a little different

Tags: tensorflow, caffe

I'm trying to convert nasnet tensorflow model to caffemodel. The `cell_stem_0` block's output is right, but when it came to `cell_stem_1/1x1`, the output feature map of my caffemodel is a little different from the tensorflow model:

All the 22 feature maps's bounding pixels are different, but the others are right.

Will a 1x1conv cause this difference? Is there any difference between the 1x1conv in `cell_stem_`0 and `cell_stem_1` (in my caffemodel, the output of `cell_stem_0/1x1` is right) ?

Comment: if your boundary features are different you should look into padding in previous layers. Is it possible caffe and tensorflow have different padding rules/values?

Comment: Formatting and typos

Comment: I have tried to send identical feature map to cell_stem_1/1x1 in caffemodel and tensorflowmodel, the output is almost the same. I think the differences in feature maps's bounding pixels are caused by the input feature map which is different in 1e-5 orders of magnitude(almost the same). However, it's interesting that the other pixels expect the boundary pixels are almost the same.